# Can't connect from outside of container to Clickhouse by HTTP on Mac OS

Tags: macos, docker, clickhouse

I'm trying to use ClickHouse with docker on Mac OS. I use next command:

```
docker run -d -p 8123:8123 --rm --name some-clickhouse-server -v /my/config/path/config.xml:/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server:latest
```

Container successfully started, but when I try to connect to it by http `curl 'http://localhost:8123'` I have an error:

> Failed to connect to localhost port 8123: Connection refused

When I connect to Clickhouse from Clickhouse-client (also using docker image) everything is OK

I ran Clickhouse-server image in `-it` mode, installed `curl`, started server and tried to connect clickhouse-server from inside of container, it's OK too

Also I tried to modify config.xml (which was copied from docker image) settings for `listen_host` (`::`, `0.0.0.0`, `::1`, `127.0.0.1`)
and for every setting I tried to connect by curl for `localhost`, `127.0.0.1`, `0.0.0.0` - nothing of this solved my problem

Comment: I think there is an error in your config file. 
When I ran `docker run -d -p 8123:8123 --name some-clickhouse-server --ulimit nofile=262144:262144 yandex/clickhouse-server`, and then `curl 'http://localhost:8123/'`, I got a `200 OK`. Could you share the content of your config.xml?

Comment: Paste here full config.xml file? And, as I mentioned, I've copied contents of config.xml from image's /etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml

Comment: I am facing same problem @Anderi Koch. I have docker-desktop installed in my mac system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Docker Toolbox on Mac OS (in conjunction with VirtualBox). So, I've migrated to Docker Desktop and this has solved my problem

Answer (score 1):

Normally, docker desktop write these details of host and container to `/etc/hosts`, after adding the `clickhouse-service` as follows has resolved this issue.

```
127.0.0.1 localhost clickhouse-service
```